# Heroku and Gandi.net

Tags: heroku

I have no clue how to set up the zones for Gandi.net and Heroku.  Here is what I currently have in the Gandi.net zone file.  It is now erroring and not going to any page:

```
@ 10800 IN A 217.70.184.38
blog 10800 IN CNAME blogs.vip.gandi.net.
imap 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
pop 10800 IN CNAME access.mail.gandi.net.
smtp 10800 IN CNAME relay.mail.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME webmail.gandi.net.
www 10800 IN CNAME app.herokuapp.com
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the period at the end of `app.herokuapp.com.` to make it a FQDN, thus the DNS resolving mechanism will be appending your zone domain to the end of it and forwarding people to `app.herokuapp.com.yourdomain.com` instead.